# Cannot launch IE7 using Selenium grid on a Virtual Machine

Tags: internet-explorer-7, virtualbox, selenium-grid

I'm trying to launch an automated test on a remote machine using Selenium Grid. The remote machine has a virtual machine that has IE7.

On the remote machine, I have the hub running using the following command:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar -role hub -port 4444"
```

On the virtual machine, I have the node running using the following command:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar -role node -port 5555 -hub http://xxxx:4444/grid/register -browser browserName="internet explorer",version=7,platform=WINDOWS
```

xxxx being the remote machine's URL.

I have the "Protected Mode settings are not the same for all zones." error. I tried changing the protected mode settings. On my local (where I run the test from) and on the remote machine, it was disabled by default, so I disabled it on the virtual machine. I still have the same error though.

The registration on the virtual machine works, and checking xxxx/grid/console shows the browser.

Anyone has any idea what I'm missing here?

EDIT: full error message:

```
internet explorer 7 (ANY): The environment you requested was unavailable. (%s)
 > Requested browser: { name: 'undefined - internet explorer 7 (ANY)',
  browserName: 'internet explorer',
  platform: 'ANY',
  version: '7',
  build: undefined,
  tags: [ 'custom', '47589137' ] }
```

> Error: { [Error: The environment you requested was unavailable.]

```
data: '{"sessionId":"","status":13,"value":{"message":"Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Protected Mode settings are not the same for all zones. Enable Protected Mode must be set to the same value (enabled or disabled) for all zones. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)...
```

I did not provide the full data provided, as it is fairly long. If there is any specific information I should look for, let me know.

EDIT2: call code:

It's using paraffin (https://github.com/vmeurisse/paraffin). The call to the parafin function is:

```
paraffin.tests(getConfig(['server', 'coverage', 'remote']), function() {
    showReportLocation();
    callback.apply(this, arguments);
});
```

with the config being:

```
server: {
    path: dir.base,
    port: 8080,
    coverageDir: dir.coverageDir
},
coverage: {
    baseDir: dir.base,
    src: dir.src,
    coverageDir: dir.coverageDir,
    copyall: true,
    filter: function(file) {
        return list_of_files;
    }
},
remote: {
    webdriverURL: 'domain',
    webdriverPort: 4444,
    url: 'http://' + os.hostname() + ':8080/rest_of_the_url',
    browsers: [
        {browserName: 'internet explorer', version: '7', platform: 'ANY'}, 
        {browserName: 'firefox', platform: 'ANY'},
        {browserName: 'chrome', platform: 'ANY'}
    ]
}
```

However, I don't think this is where the problem lies. With exactly the same code, and exactly the same command to link the node to the hub, but the command launched from my (physical) machine (albeit on IE8), it works.

Comment: what is the error you are recieving ??

Comment: What is your code for requesting the webdriver session?

Comment: It's actually using the paraffin plugin (https://github.com/vmeurisse/paraffin). Post updated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a workaround to the issue.

It seems that the issue only occurs when the virtual machine is on the same machine as the remote machine. After launching a virtual machine independently from the remote machine, it worked.

Comment: Not understanding what you are talking about.  Are you saying running the Hub vm separate from the Node vms?

Comment: Almost. When the Node VM is launched by the Hub (physical) machine, it wasn't working. However, when the Nodes are launched from another physical machine, it manages to connect to the Hub.

Comment: Ok, but I would double check that.  Most likely the symptom you are seeing is due to a misconfiguration somewhere.  Why would you set the IE platform property to "ANY".  Did you try the more specific "WINDOWS"?  Also, I think most people have stopped testing IE6 and IE7, in favor of 8,9, and 10 because it is rare that people use those.  Do you have some specific reason why you are testing IE7?

Comment: I have tried to specify WINDOWS, to no avail. As for testing IE7, I wish we did not have to test it, but it's a client requirement. We only dropped IE6 very recently... But for this issue specifically, I don't think it's related to the browser, as it is the Selenium node and the hub that don't manage to communicate.